# Exchange LWin and LAlt

Tags: autohotkey

This is my code.

```
#InputLevel 1
LAlt::LWin
LWin::LAlt

#InputLevel 2
!a::
#a::
tooltip You pressed %A_ThisHotkey%.
return
```

From my understanding, InputLevel 2 is executed first, then InputLevel 1, which means if I press LAlt key and a key, screen will show I pressed !a, if I press LWin key and a key, screen will show I pressed #a.

However actually my screen shows nothing. My key is not captured.

Do I miss anything? I want to capture hotkey first then do remapping.

Comment: your script works 100% fine for me.. I get the correct tooltips :/ (using ahk vers. 1.1.22.2)

Comment: @Blauhirn I use the exactly same version! How come it doesn't work in my side? Do you know possible reasons?

Comment: @Blauhirn By the way I use Windows 7 and keyboard is Filco 67.

Comment: I really have no idea, sorry. Note that you can click on the ahk symbol in the task bar and see infos about the running script. good luck

Comment: Could be caused by the keyboard, if it is using non-standard keycodes. Did it come with a config utility?

Answer (score 1):

When you press `alt + a` the `LAlt::LWin` hotkey is being fired first and the `!a::` hotkey is being ignored. If you want to fire the `!a::` regardless of the first hotkey fired you must add `~` on the `LAlt::LWin` hotkey so its native function (necessary to perform alt+a) isn't going to be blocked.

It may be easier to understand with this example:

```
#InputLevel 1
~LAlt:: tooltip First pressed %A_ThisHotkey%.
~LWin:: tooltip First pressed %A_ThisHotkey%.

#InputLevel 2
!a::
#a::
tooltip Then pressed %A_ThisHotkey%.
return
```

ps: if you also want to ignore extra modifiers that are (maybe) being held down you can add the wildcard `*` on the `!a::` and `#a::` hotkeys. So, in the end, the hotkeys would look like this: `~LAlt::LWin` `~LWin::LAlt` `*!a::` and `*#a::`